# Defining default arguments for a macro?

Tags: optional-arguments, key-value

Quick question, is there a way to define default arguments for a macro? For example, I have a page filled with these:

```
\TextField[width=2cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{Question 1}
\TextField[width=4cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{Question 2}
\TextField[width=3cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{Question 3}
\TextField[width=5cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{Question 4}
```

Can I tell it the `height` and `bordercolor` somewhere so I don't have to repeat those at every line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Most packages provide global settings somehow, but it really depends on the specific case.

Comment: Well it's `\TextField` I use.. so from the `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: If you were to define your macro, e.g. `\newcommand{\MyText}[2]{\TextField[width=2cm,height=10pt,#1,bordercolor=stuff]{#2}}` I think the you could pass the `height`a second time, i.e. `\MyText{height=15pt}{Question 1}`. I believe the last definition will be used. I can't test this now... Can you give that a try?

Comment: @Dendory And what if you use `amsmath` as well which modifies the behaviour of `\@ifnextchar`, which can modify the behaviour of `\TextField`? As well, by not providing the MWE, you force any of the volunteers to make it themselves, which costs their time. However, it is you who want help, not them.

Comment: You could also define a macro using \newcommand{\pete}[1]{\Textfield[width=2cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{#1}} then use \pete{Question 1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @Markus's comment and modified it slightly:

```
\newcommand{\q}[2]{\TextField[width=#1,height=10pt,bordercolor=stuff]{‌​#2}}
...
\q{3cm}{Question}
```

Answer (score 4):

A version with either the standard `\@ifnextchar` way and the more sophisticated `\NewDocumentCommand` from `xparse` package.

Please note that in the `\MakeMyTextField[width=10cm]{}` way, the default argument is overruled of course, as well as in `\MyTextField`.

A better approach would use `keyval` or `xkeyval` or (if really needed ;-)) `pgfkeys`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\MakeMyTextField@@opt}[2][width=2cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=blue]{%
\TextField[#1]{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\MakeMyTextField@@noopt}[1]{
\MakeMyTextField@@opt{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\MakeMyTextField}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\MakeMyTextField@@opt}{\MakeMyTextField@@noopt}
}%


\NewDocumentCommand{\MyTextField}{+O{width=2cm,height=10pt,bordercolor=blue}+m}{%
  \TextField[#1]{#2}%
}%




\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \MakeMyTextField{Question 1}

\item \MakeMyTextField{Question 2}

\item \MakeMyTextField[width=10cm]{Question 3}

\item \MyTextField{Question 4}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply preset new default values; it's still possible to override them locally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setkeys{Field}{height=10pt,bordercolor=green}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \TextField{Question 1}

\item \TextField{Question 2}

\item \TextField[width=10cm]{Question 3}

\item \TextField[height=30pt,bordercolor=red]{Question 4}

\item \TextField{Question 5}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]